# Threads and IndexOutOfRange exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, outofrangeexception

[image: Note that in the locals i = 3]

As you can clearly see the highest index of the args[] is 2, however the iterator somehow gets to 3.
Explanation?

Edit: The commented Thread.Sleep magically fixes the problem.

Comment: Anything is possible with code that is not thread safe ...

Comment: there are two threads if i am not mistaken...the main thread and temp...the main thread controls the for loop..and temp[] controls the string array...the `Thread.Sleep(1)` fixes the problem by forcing the main thread to sleep for 1 millisecond..i am i right?

Comment: You should remove your extra thread and verify you get the exception.  Thread testing 101!

Comment: This is a matter of the lambda capturing the index, `i`. It has little to do with threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by `i` being declared outside of the for loop, for the entire for loop. Since there is no guarantee that the `Thread` is executed at that point, the value of `i` can change before the `Thread` executes. You can "resolve" this by declaring a local variable in the for loop.

```
//for loop ..
var localIndex = i;
var temp = new Thread(() => PrintOut(args[localIndex], IsFilePath(args[localIndex])));
temp.Start();
//for loop ..
```

EDIT: Also, can you please post a code snippet next time, saves me having to write out the code again :P

Comment: Right, the `for` loop's incrementor (`i++`) executes before the body of the thread is invoked.  Thus, `i` can be incremented to `3` before the thread actually runs.

Comment: Always thought the call to Thread.Start actually starts the thread.
"Once a thread is in the ThreadState.Running state, the operating system can schedule it for execution."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
for (var i = 0; i< args.Length; i++)
{
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
int i = 0;

loop:

if (i < args.Length)
{
    i++;
    goto loop;
}
```

so you see that `i` is incremented to 3 in order to check your condition.

Of course, `new Thread(() => PrintOut(args[i], IsFilePath(args[i])))` is never actually called when `i` is 3. However, since there is only one instance of `i` which the loop changes on each iteration, the execution that started when `i` was 2 is affected when `i` is incremented to 3.

To fix this, you need to copy the value of `i` into a new variable on each loop iteration. This copy will not be updated by the `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i< args.Length; i++)
{
     var copy = i;
     Thread temp = new Thread(() => PrintOut(args[copy], IsFilePath(args[copy]))
}
```